# How do I debug when the system freezes or when it crashes back to login?

Tags: debug

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and I was wonder what a good way is to debug when something crashes?

For example: I installed 11.04 and the default media player banshee makes my laptop crash after a few minutes of playing music. Since the system completely freezes and there is not error message it's hard to find out what is wrong.

Second problem I have is that sometimes the system crashes to login. I am suspecting it to be a Chromium or Flash but I am not 100% sure.

So anybody got some tips on how to debug stuff like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not login using the login GUI after such a crash. Switch to a text-based login by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. Login with your username and password. Errors during a X session are appended to `~/.xsession-errors`, but this file is overwritten every login. Make a backup of this file by executing:

```
mv ~/.xsession-errors{,.1}
```

This will rename the `.xsession-errors` file to `.xsession_errors.1`. Replace the `.1` if you want a different suffix. You can now logout from this shell by executing `exit`.

Check the system logfiles in `/var/log`. The most interesting files are:

```
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/Xorg.0.log (for the current session)
/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old (for previous session)
/var/log/?dm.log (gdm for gnome, kdm for KDE)
```

Comment: why not mention `/var/crash/`? This is where `/var/log/apport.log` sent me.

Comment: `/var/crash` does not really contain human-readable error messages, but a file named like `_usr_bin_Xorg.0.crash` that can be submitted using Apport.

Comment: That is what I meant `apport.log` told me a specific *.crash file to check; `ls -ltrh /var/crash/` confirmed that it was generated during the previous crash; but I was thinking that next time I might start with `ls -ltrh /var/crash/`.

Comment: Useless, cause Ctrl + Alt + F1 does nothing (and I didn't change any shortcuts).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to look at the log directory (/var/log/). You can find any crash or regular logs in there.

Some applications can create crash logs in their own directories. For example, ~/.banshee in your home directory.

Comment: Crash is a vague term. What exactly do you do if the system freezes completely and nothing out of the ordinary is in the logs?

Comment: @mikewhatever Necro but found this looking for same type issues.  Is 2018 and I'm on Ubuntu 18 and is stable until I debug my application. The whole system freezes and crashes.