# Can't login after upgrade

Tags: 10.04, login, login-screen

When ubuntu loads up, it asks to log in.

When I press my username or "other", login window flicks a bit and is right back where it was, nothing happens. Can't log in.

Any ideas what's wrong?

xsession-error:

> (gnome-terminal:3401): Gtk-WARNING **:
>    Failed to load type module: (null)
>   `menu_proxy_module_load':
>    gnome-terminal: undefined symbol:
>    menu_proxy_modu le_load

Comment: Sounds like it crashed. Could you get your `.xsession-errors` fileby following [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/q/38367/6969)? Did you upgrade from 9.10 to 10.04?

Comment: @Lekensteyn there is a quite strange error indeed.

Comment: please put the whole file on http://paste.ubuntu.com, that warning is not critical.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the upgrade didn't finish.

To complete the upgrade, boot up, and then at the login screen you'll need to drop to a ttyy (a terminal).

To do that, use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl-Alt-F1.

Login with your username and password, then run the following:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Let that finish, and then you can reboot by running `sudo reboot`.

Your system should be back to normal.

Comment: Also make sure you have enough free space to install.