# Login goes nowhere after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: xubuntu, login, login-screen, bug-reporting

After upgrading to Xubuntu 13.10 I rebooted once and found that after login, regardless of account, I end up stuck after the login window disappears, with a movable pointer and the background from the login screen. I am running ecryptfs on the main account's home partition but even the guest login yields the same result. What do I need to fix this?

(I can reach a text terminal so I can post logs on request.)

(I've tried this question's solution to no effect: [Can't login after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47594/cant-login-after-upgrade?rq=1))

Reinstalling lightdm and xubuntu-desktop also had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a number of packages were marked for upgrade but these operations were never applied. After manually upgrading all possible available packages, `lightdm` still does not work but `gdm` does, which is an acceptable workaround for me.