# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 freeze sometimes?

Tags: freeze

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 on a usb-stick (yes I *installed* it on a usb-stick) and sometimes it randomly freezes. When it freezes I can't do anything, I have to force shutdown my computer. Is there a way I can stop it from freezing?

the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` is:

```
compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2992] (rev 02)
  Subsystem: Dell 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:01da]
  Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Please say what to do next

Comment: is it meet your computer specification

Comment: No, that is not the problem. But I do use Windows 10 and it never freezes.

Comment: can you write the output of lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA

Comment: what is that? ..

Comment: list of vga drivers

Comment: no open terminal and write  lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA  it will list your drivers

Comment: and append output on your question

Comment: ok here is the list jacob@Ubuntu-Stick16:~$  lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2992] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell 82Q963/Q965 Integrated Graphics Controller [1028:01da]
 Kernel driver in use: i915                 for @Mohamed Slama

Comment: do you have an external vga not installed ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I debug when the system freezes or when it crashes back to login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38367/how-do-i-debug-when-the-system-freezes-or-when-it-crashes-back-to-login)

Comment: Have you tried installing to a hdd? Maybe your USB stick is going bad.

Comment: I am not going to install to my hard drive, but when I did install it to hdd it did the same thing.  But no I know my usb stick is not going bad because I only bought it 3 weeks ago

Comment: Kernel panic probably, why? who knows... it's like the Universe, a mystery. XD

Comment: I think it is a problem with the flash drive. I bought a new flash drive that is 64 gb and installed Ubuntu on it and it did not freeze at all. (My old flash drive was 8 gb)