# Ubuntu crashed during youtube video

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, crash, youtube

I bought [Lenovo ThinkCentre M710q](https://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/desktops-and-all-in-ones/thinkcentre/m-series-tiny/ThinkCentre-M710q/p/10MRCTO1WWENUS0) and installed Ubuntu 18.04 on it. 
During playing Youtube videos, Ubuntu freezed suddenly and then I have to restart computer manually. It happens every time during playing Youtube videos.
The display resolution is:

```
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
```

and graphics card is:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

I was curious and installed Windows 10 on the computer with following driver:

[image]

and I can play several Youtube videos simultaneously. It never crashed.

Does it exist a suitable Intel HD Graphics 530 driver for Ubuntu 18.04? Or what do I have to do?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: Can you please refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/38369/175814 and add the content of the recommended log files (or links to it if they're too long) to your question? In a vanilla Ubuntu 18.04 setup your display manager would be GDM.

Comment: I updated the kernel of linux to 4.17 and it seems that it does not crashed anymore. But I will post the log anyway.

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please consider to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept your answer. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, the drivers for the integrated graphics is included in the kernel. However, it seems linux drivers tend to cause more issues than in Windows.

I see two possible solutions:

1. In Google Chrome(I'm assuming) settings, disable hardware acceleration.
2. try downgrading/upgrading the linux kernel

Comment: What kernel would you suggest the questioner use, of the ones available to 18.04?

Comment: I found the kernel website on http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/.  My actual linux kernel is `Linux 4.15.0-22-generic`. How to upgrade it?