# System freezes while using Firefox

Tags: firefox, freeze

Most of time when I use Firefox my system freezes and needs to be restarted. Sometimes I use other apps and need to restart the system after the system. The system is updated. Firefox usually freezes when I'm on YouTube.

How can fix this?

My Ubuntu version is 18. It happen in this new version. Before the update it was good.

Comment: You're going to need to post more details, perhaps including log files, screenshots of the issue, or output. See this for details on providing relevant information: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38367/how-do-i-debug-when-the-system-freezes-or-when-it-crashes-back-to-login

Comment: Also on KUbuntu 20.04 with Firefox 81.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be because Firefox does not release memory once it has taken it so that every page you have loaded up stays in memory.

As far as I know, there is only one way of dealing with this problem:

**Close Firefox periodically down and relaunch it** or try to use an alternative web browser until Firefox updated and issue disappeared

Comment: you can also check Mozilla support here : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-hangs-or-not-responding